# How to count non-zero numbers in a comma separated string in oracle sql

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle, count

Want to count non-zero numbers from a comma separated string in oracle 12.10.
If my column has data as 2000,300,0,0 then count it as 2.

This gives me 2000 and 300 as result but what's next to count it.

`select regexp_substr('2000,300,0,0','[^,]+',1,level) from dual connect BY to_number(regexp_substr('2000,300,0,0', '[^,]+',1,level)) > 0`

Thanks for helping me. I know I am missing a basic step and that is haunting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only integers:

```sql
select regexp_count('2000,300,0,0', '([1-9]+0*)+') cnt from dual
```

Comment: Thank you. The data here can be 0,0,0,0 and this counts right as zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a recursive query:

```
select 1 
    + regexp_count('2000,300,0,0', ',') 
    - regexp_count('2000,300,0,0', '(^|,)0(,|$)')
from dual
```

Rationale: to get the number of elements in the CSV list, you can count the number of commas, and add `1`; then, we substract the count of elements whose value is `0`.

Comment: It's incorrect for `2000,300,0,0`, because it would match the first `,0,` but then it won't match the last `0`, so your version returns 3. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dada0/5/0)

Comment: Alex, your version was right which you deleted. Pl add that again.

Comment: @RashmiM I'll post it as a comment `select regexp_count('2000,300,0,0', ',') + 1 - regexp_count('2000,300,0,0','(^|,)0+') from dual`